# PHP contact form not working right

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I've been working on a contact form. I have added used the POST method to send it to a set email address. It doesn't seem to be working though. It just runs and stops as if the code is broken. The HTML and PHP are below.

```
<form action="contact-form.php" method="post" id="contact-form" name="contact-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Your name</label> <input class=
                        "form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email address</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email"
                        type="email">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="phone">Phone</label> <input class=
                        "form-control" id="phone" name="phone" type="text">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message">Your message</label> 
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name=
                        "message" rows="6">
                        </textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="submit">
                        <input class="button button-small" type="submit"
                        value="Send">
                    </div>
                </form>



<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = "gfrazer@hotmail.co.uk";
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $name . " " . " wrote the following: " . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    header('Location: http://www.google.co.uk');
}

?>
```

Comment: IF you are working from localhost you need a few tweaks to be able to send mail

Comment: Could you post full code? `<form>` starting tag is missing.

Comment: You could try sending the email with the from, to, name, phone and message filled out as string already, to see if your form is broken? I'm missing the <form> tag, which tells you where to send the information to and how you want to have it sent there (GET or POST).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a name to your submit button. From your snippit, you have no `$_POST['submit']`:

```
<form action="contact-form.php" method="post" id="contact-form" name="contact-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="email">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">Phone</label> <input class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">Your message</label> 
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" rows="6"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="submit">
        <!-- ADD name="submit" -->
        <input name="submit" class="button button-small"  type="submit" value="Send" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Also, make sure the file is called contact-form.php

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked great. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks again for the quick response.